# Problems on Ruby, gem and redis installation on MacOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, rubygems, command

I believed that I successfully installed Ruby and RedisDump, however, when I run `redis-dump` or `redis-load`, terminal just told me "command not found". I don't know how to solve this problem.

The point is I had problem on installation of Ruby and Redisdump before, but I just tried a lot fixing suggestions online, and luckily solved the problem, I believed. So I don't know if I truly properly installed Ruby and RedisDump, or is this just another problem I need to solve?

To be honest, I am very new to this coding world but I am here to learn, thank you guys!

Comment: How did  you install Ruby and RedisDump? What troubleshooting have you tried? There is a system Ruby. Did you just install over that? Did you use RVM? RBENV?

Comment: I used rbenv to install Ruby and ruby gems, following the instruction here https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv , then I run "gem install redis-dump" to install redisdump.

Comment: Did you tried starting a new shell session to load rbenv settings? what do you get with `which ruby` or `which gem`? maybe you're still using old system ruby

Comment: I opened a new tab and tried to run the codes again but still "command not found". for 'which ruby', I got this "/Users/yuefuxiao/.rbenv/shims/ruby"; for 'which gem', I got this "/Users/yuefuxiao/.rbenv/shims/gem".

Comment: Have you run `rbenv rehash`?

Comment: Also what does your PATH look like? Run `env` to see your PATH among other settings.